# Is there a decent alternative to Oracle's VirtualBox with similar UX, feature set, and stability?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-box

I'm looking for an alternative to Oracle's (formerly Sun's) VirtualBox virtualization suite.
There have been no changes in the last six months or so, and I'm worried the virtualization suite might get abandoned. In the last year or two specifically, but ever since Oracle took over Sun in general, VirtualBox development has been slowing down noticeably. In order to have ample time to move to a different solution, I'm looking for alternatives before waiting for Oracle to announce abandoning VirtualBox, or something similar.

Hence, I'm looking for something very similar to VirtualBox, especially when it comes to these requirements:

- General ease of use. Using VirtualBox is very easy, both when the host is the local machine or a server. Some additional things like shared folder between host and guest OSes, that ease data transfer would be also appreciated.
- Easy migration of guest VMs. I can "pack up" and export a guest VM and import it elsewhere on a different host. The process is very simple and intuitive, moving VMs is as easy as moving a file over the network. This might not be a very modern or efficient workflow, but it's what we use.
- Cross-Platformity. VirtualBox (the hypervisor) runs on Linux and Windows, I need my alternative to do the same.
- Similar availability of "Guest Additions", i.e. a driver pack for a wide range (Linux distros and Windows versions, dating back to Windows 7) making running the guest OS conveniently integrated into my host desktop environment. Backwards compatability however, is very important, as some software solution I use requires older versions of Windows.
- Support for a wide range of guest OSes. Especially older versions of Windows and MS-DOS.
- Ability to make snapshots, and run the same snapshot on each boot of the VM.

Perhaps an important note: I'm not really looking for performance. VirtualBox isn't known to be terribly performant and/or efficient, and in fact it's not that important in my case. A solution that is free would be preferred but a commercial solution is also interesting to me. Security is not a big issue either, as the guest VMs aren't able to access the internet directly, there is ample security on the premises. The VMs are only run from a specific, pre-configured snapshot. The VMs never run for more than perhaps six hours and no data is saved when the VM is powered down. Things like resource - specifically memory efficiency - isn't important either. Stability should be somewhat similar to VirtualBox. I don't need to have the VMs running for months or so, but it should not crash randomly when working with it.